# GCP bucket file access using PHP curl using JSON key

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am new to GCP. I have a function which outputs a CSV file to the GCP Cloud Storage. I am trying to access the file using PHP.

What I have done so far:

1. I have created a service account using GCP IAM and have given it access as Storage Object Viewer.
2. I have also obtained the json key from the IAM.

What commands would I need to use in my PHP script (hosted on a different web server) to retrieve the file using CURL and how do I use the json authentication key?

I apologize in advance if this is in the documentation somewhere, I found it very convoluted and over whelming. Any advice or direction is appreciated.

---

**Update:**

Based on the comments below here is a link to the [google-cloud-php github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) which I found. I am not sure if this is the best resource to begin.

Comment: Start with the Google Cloud PHP SDK and the code examples.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the comment. Could you please share a link, I have somethings I found on Google, but not sure if I am in the right place.

Comment: Please do it the other way around. Share the links in your question.

Comment: I have added the link I have found. Is that it?

Comment: Did you try the example in the documentation? In your link is another link to an extensive example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/

Comment: No I did not. But I will now. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to add that this link helped quite a bit https://quick.work/?page=view-blog&id=26

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Cloud Storage library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) for php, more specifically, how to [download objects](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.123.0/storage/storageobject?method=downloadToFile).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get an accesstoken for Authentification. For this you need the json authentification key.

This page was a great help for me:
https://www.it-swarm.dev/de/curl/wie-kann-man-mit-curl-eine-verbindung-zum-google-drive-api-herstellen/806069468/

Maybe this PHP-code helps you a little bit:

```
    function get_Google_accesstoken($scope,$credfile,$proxy,$timetoexpiration){
    #Developers Info at developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
        $GoogleApiKeyInfo=GoogleApiKeyInfo($credfile);
        $Header=array();
        $Header["alg"]="RS256";
        $Header["typ"]="JWT";
        $ClaimSet["iss"]=$GoogleApiKeyInfo["client_email"];
        $ClaimSet["scope"]=$scope;
        $ClaimSet["aud"]=$GoogleApiKeyInfo["token_uri"];
        $ClaimSet["iat"]=time();
        $ClaimSet["exp"]=$ClaimSet["iat"]+($timetoexpiration);
        $Jws=base64_encode(json_encode($Header)).".".base64_encode(json_encode($ClaimSet));
        $OpenSslRslts=openssl_sign($Jws,$Signature,$GoogleApiKeyInfo["private_key"],OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        $Jwt=$Jws.".".base64_encode($Signature);
        $SendVars=array();
        $SendVars["grant_type"]=("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
        $SendVars["assertion"]=$Jwt;
        $SendVars=http_build_query($SendVars);


    
    $ch=curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GoogleApiKeyInfo["token_uri"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $SendVars);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $response=json_decode($response);
    return $response;

}
```

you find hints for $scope at [developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes](http://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)
$proxy is only used if you need a proxy and $timetoexpiration has no influence, because your accesstoken is always valid for 60 minutes